# how to capture the keydown event of the AVPlayer?

Tags: swift, macos, avkit

I'm writing a video player using the AVkit under macOS, the AVPlayer can response to the keyboard event, for example, space key down to pause/play the video, left arrow key down to move back the video.
I want to capture the keydown event, so that I can do more controls to the AVPlayer, how to do it?
the following is my sample code:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

public class VideoItem: ObservableObject {
    @Published var player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
    @Published var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?

    func open(_ url: URL) {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: url)

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        self.playerItem = playerItem

        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)


    }
}

public struct PlayerView: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var player: AVPlayer

    var titles:[Title] = []
    public init(player:Binding<AVPlayer>,currentSeconds:Binding<Double>,subtitleFile:Binding<String>,currentTitle:Binding<Title?>)
    {
        self._player = player


    }

    public func updateNSView(_ NSView: NSView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<PlayerView>) {
        guard let view = NSView as? AVPlayerView else {
            debugPrint("unexpected view")
            return
        }
      //  status = player.timeControlStatus.rawValue

        view.player = player


    }

    public func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let av = AVPlayerView(frame: .zero)

        return av
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v got a solution, to capture the keydown event, We can create a subclass from AVPlayerView and override it's keydown event.

Comment: AVPlayerView's keyDown override is no longer called (at least not on Xcode 13.4 and macOS 12.3.1).  Clicking on the player can be disabled using:

 internal override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool {
  return false
 }

But there seems to be no easy way to stop space from happening.